# Get data from django database

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

So,how get data from django database?I have django models and created 2 objects there.I want to get 2 objects and write in html file. admin panel: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WUZr.png

view.py

```
    def vds(request):
    HTML_STRING = render_to_string("vds.html", context=context1)
    return HttpResponse(HTML_STRING)
VDSTARIFS_obj = VDSTARIFS.objects.get(id=1)
context1 = {
    "prise": VDSTARIFS_obj.prise,
}
```

file with models

````
class VDSTARIFS( models.Model):
    prise = models.CharField(max_length= 10,)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.prise)```
````

Comment: 1) There is something strange with the indent of your code, python will not work if you do not indent correctly 2) All the lines you put after return will never be executed 3) Move lines 2,4,5,6 before lien 2 and should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Referring to the Django docs:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial03/#a-shortcut-render

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Question

def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    context = {'latest_question_list': latest_question_list}
    return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)
```

### Edited for your model

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import VDSTARIFS

def vds(request):
    ALL_VDSTARIFS = VDSTARIFS.objects.all()
    FIRST_VDSTARIF = ALL_VDSTARIFS[:1]

    # Get prise
    prise = FIRST_VDSTARIF.prise

    # Alternatives to print 'prise' in template 

    # Pass only the first item of vds list
    context = {
        "FIRST_VDSTARIF": FIRST_VDSTARIF
    }

    # Pass prise only
    
    context = {
        "prise": prise
    }

    # All records in html also the needed one in separated item
    context = {
        "ALL_VDSTARIFS": VDSTARIFS,
        "FIRST_VDSTARIF": FIRST_VDSTARIF
    }

    return render(request, 'vds.html', context)
}
```

In template you can use if
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#if

```
{# Runs along all tarifs and print only one, not good. #}
{% for vdstarif in ALL_VDSTARIFS %}
 {% if vdstarifs.id == "1" %}
   {{ vdstarif.prise }}
 {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{# Only print the needed one #}
{{ FIRST_VDSTARIF.prise }}


{# Print prise #}
{{ prise }}
```

You might follow python and django coding conventions and my suggestions.

Rename VDSTARIFS -> VdsTarif (look at your admin page, Django adds 's' to your model to make it plural)

Use singular names for your models and add a suffix to variable names in views like vdstarif_list.

For "prise" field use DecimalField, looks like it is a CharField. Is it prise or price?
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#decimalfield

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import VdsTarif

def vds(request):
   vdstarif_list = VdsTarif.objects.all()

   context = {
        "vdstarif_list" : vfstarif_list[:0].prise
   }

   return render(request, 'vds.html', context)
```